# Is Clojure considered Lispy or Schemey?

Tags: clojure, lisp, scheme

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Clojure closer to Scheme or Common Lisp from a beginner's perspective?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412981/is-clojure-closer-to-scheme-or-common-lisp-from-a-beginners-perspective)

Clojure is a Lisp dialect that runs on the JVM.
Is Clojure considered Lispy or Schemey?
I mean is it like Lisp or like Scheme?

Comment: Same as [Is Clojure closer to Scheme or Common Lisp from a beginner's perspective?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412981/is-clojure-closer-to-scheme-or-common-lisp-from-a-beginners-perspective).

Comment: If you meant Common Lisp when you wrote "Lisp", this is a duplicate, as @Matthew pointed out. If you meant something else, please explain, because Scheme is a Lisp and thus it makes no sense to differentiate between Lisp and Scheme.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If by "Lispy" you mean "like Common Lisp," then...

Clojure is "Lispy" because it has full (nonhygienic) macros and doesn't guarantee tail-call optimization (except with `recur`).

Clojure is "Schemey" because it has a single namespace for both functions and values (it is a Lisp-1).

Comment: Scheme doesn't has full (nonhygienic) and guarantee tail-call optimization?

Comment: Also, is it safe to say that Clojure combines the best features from the two worlds (Common Lisp and Scheme)?

Comment: @El Gusto  Not at all. Clojure is missing most of the "best" features from Scheme, such as fully-hygienic macros, proper tail-call optimization, first-class continuations, etc.

Comment: @El Gusto I think Clojure offers an excellent array of features, taking the good from other Lisps and even some non-Lispy languages and trying to keep out the bad. One of the best things about Clojure is that it's hosted on the JVM. The JVM, while being a great thing and bringing a lot to the table (a mature, stable, supported platform, not to mention enough libraries to swim in), does bring a few limitations, one of which is the fact that the JVM (and therefore Clojure) doesn't have proper tail recursion. However, in most cases, you can use 'recur' instead.

Answer (score 10):

Lisp has mainly two meanings:

- Lisp is a family of programming language, starting with the original Lisp in 1958.

In this sense Scheme, Clojure, Emacs Lisp, Common Lisp, Logo, ... are all somewhat 'Lispy'.

- Lisp is a family of language with one main branch: Lisp, Lisp 1.5, MacLisp, Lisp Machine Lisp, Common Lisp.

One can see that it is possible to run decades old Lisp code with very few changes in Common Lisp.

In this view, neither Scheme nor Clojure are particular 'Lispy', since they are widely incompatible with the 'main branch' and with the historic Lisp.

Clojure is a new Lisp dialect that is mostly incompatible with all other Lisps and also with the historic Lisp. Names of functionality, identifiers, syntax, etc. are all different. In my view it is as far from CL as it is from Scheme.

Answer (score 5):

When people say "Schemey" they tend to mean "Lisp-1" vs. "Lisp-2", which is historically the distinction. Clojure is schemey in that fashion.

But beyond those, Clojure is stylistically more like very modern lisp sensibilities. Probably the most notable predecessor to clojure in this modern style is Arc. If anything, Clojure is arc-ish: it prefers constructs with reduced nesting depth (see clojure and arc let vs. common lisp or scheme let); both are distinct runtimes nested within larger, more generic interpreter runtimes that give a larger library for free; and both value brevity in names as opposed to the insanely long names in the common lisp spec (e.g., multiple-value-bind).

Clojure is arc-ish.